# Get JSON paths to value from JSON

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to write a func to get all paths to values from a yaml file and I don't know know how that possible, here is my code:

```
func getpath(fileyaml) string {

   if _, err := os.Stat(fileyaml); err == nil {
   bfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileyaml)
   bjson, err := yaml.YAMLToJSON(bfile)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("YAMLToJSON err: %v\n", err)
   }

   json := string(bjson)

   println json
   paths := ? // don't know 
    return path
```

here my yaml file :

```
sentinel:
  number: 3
server:
  number: 7
config:
  fere_size: 5
lcmea:
  eza_ze: all
```

my function will convert it to a json: `{"config":{"fere_size":5},"lcmea":{"eza_hooks":"all"},"sentinel":{"number":3},"server":{"number":7}}`

the output that i want :

```
sentinel.number=3, server.number=3,config.fere_size=5,lcmea.eza_ze=all
```

how to parse this json in order to get this desired output?

I'm using "github.com/tidwall/gjson" to read the yaml and convert it to json

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936530/read-config-in-a-custom-format-from-yaml-file/49937921

Comment: why do you need to convert it to json, you could unmarshal the YAML into a struct and then print the required fields of that struct

Comment: how could you please show an example because my yaml change it's dynamic

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you could do it: https://play.golang.org/p/7yLq_PDLdXF

It is pretty naive and definitely could be improved, but it may give you an idea about how to parse the `yaml` file and then print the output in your desired format:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-yaml/yaml"
)

var data = `
sentinel:
  number: 3
server:
  number: 7
config:
  fere_size: 5
lcmea:
  eza_ze: all
`

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]map[string]interface{})

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    out := []string{}
    for k, v := range m {
        for j, i := range v {
            out = append(out, fmt.Sprintf("%s.%v=%v", k, j, i))
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(strings.Join(out, ", "))
}
```

It will return:

```
$ go run main.go
sentinel.number=3, server.number=7, config.fere_size=5, lcmea.eza_ze=all
```

It is using https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml, check more  examples on the `README.md`